# Store data to other table and get the id

Tags: php, jtable, jmodel

I'm using a method to store information in another table. This is how I'm doing that:

```
public static function CreateMail($userid, $title, $state = 1)
{           
    $maildata['userid'] = $userid;
    $maildata['title']  = $title;
    $maildata['state']  = $state;               

    $row = JTable::getInstance('Mail','BestiaTable');
    $row->bind($maildata);
    $row->check();
    $storemessage = $row->store();

    return $storemessage;                       
}
```

This is working fine - but one problem remains: I would like to get the id of the saved data.

How can I do that?

Edit: The given answer worked on 3.4.48 but on 3.5 `$row->id` always returns `NULL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$row` contains inserted data with PK. So `$row->id` is id of the saved data.
So you can do

```
 public static function CreateMail($userid, $title, $state = 1)
    {           
        $maildata['userid']     =       $userid;
        $maildata['title']      =       $title;
        $maildata['state']      =       $state;             

        $row=JTable::getInstance('Mail','BestiaTable');
        $row->bind($maildata);
        $row->check();
        $storemessage = $row->store();

        return $row->id;                       
    }
```

Comment: Hm, it worked fine. But since Joomla 3.5 it no longer works :-(

Answer (score 1):

To get the last insertId use:

```
$newID = $row->insertId();
```

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/JDatabase/insertid)
You have to call it just after

```
$store = $row->store();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. On Joomla 3.5 the PDO driver does not return an id.

This is discussed and will be solved: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/9534