# After upgrade to 3.5: return $row->id (last saved item) does not work

Tags: development, custom-component, jtable

I would like to get the ID of an item that I recently saved using store-method.

On Joomla 3.4.48 I was able to use this source:

```
$data['userid'] = $userid;
$data['title'] = $title;                
$data['content'] = $content;

$data['state'] = $state;

// Lets store it!    
$row = JTable::getInstance('Message','BestiaTable');
$row->bind($data);
$row->check();
$store = $row->store(); 

if($store)                        return $row->id;
```

Now $row->id is always `NULL`.

How can I change that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store data to other table and get the id](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10627/store-data-to-other-table-and-get-the-id)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. On Joomla 3.5 the PDO driver does not return an id.

This is discussed and will be solved: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/9534

Answer (score 0):

To get the last insertId use:

```
$newID = $row->insertId();
```

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/JDatabase/insertid)
You have to call it just after

```
$store = $row->store();
```

Comment: Hm, unfortunately this still returns NULL.